# What is the recommeded way of updating when using `pyproject.toml' and `setuptools`

Tags: python, pip, setuptools, pyproject.toml

I am/was operating under the assumpion that `pyproject.toml` is supposed to be a unified metadata file, replacing others (`setup.*`, `requirements.txt`...), which worked for the most part for me.

However, I have not found a way to update all depended on packages like `pip install -r requirements.txt --upgrade` would do.

Running `pip install  . -U` has no effect if all depended on packages are already present but not neccessarily on latest version.

An excerpt from my `pyproject.toml`:

```ini
[project]
name = "myapp"
version = "0.1.0"
readme = "README.md"
requires-python = ">=3.11"

dependencies = [
    "fastapi",
    "uvicorn[standard]",
    "websocket",
    "jinja2",
    "pydantic",
    "surrealdb",
    "humanize",
    "pendulum",
    "icecream",
    "pyotp",
    "webauthn"
]

[build-system]
requires = ["setuptools", "setuptools-scm"]
build-backend = "setuptools.build_meta"
```

How do I update this? Is this why I keep seeing a `requirements.txt` alongside `pyproject.toml` in projects?

Comment: `pip install -U --upgrade-strategy=eager .`

Comment: @phd Would you explain this to me? Even though I understand  the command itself, I don't understand "how does it know" where to look when it comes to dependencies?

Comment: I mean, as far as I know, pip itself by default knows where to look for dep., primarily through metadata provided in packages themselves, then it queries PyPI for available packg. and their version and then they apply upgrade. I just can't process how do you tell pip look here and here, except explicitily saying e.g. "requirements.txt.

Comment: @phd Thank you. They likely reason why I did not take notice of the existing question is that it explicitly asks updating dependencies of dependencies

Comment: With `pip install .` it looks into `pyproject.toml`, `setup.cfg` and `setup.py`, collects a list of explicit dependencies and upgrade them. Then it list dependencies of dependencies. And so on, recursive. With `pip install -r requirements.txt` the first level of explicit dependencies are listed in the file, the recursive rest is the same.